# What's the best algorithm to calculate a total price from price breakdowns?

Tags: algorithm

I am currently wondering what would be the best way to calculate a "total" price from a given list of price breakdowns.

For instance let's consider this list of price breakdowns:

- [user1, service1]=5$
- [user1, service1, service2]=15$
- [user2, service1]=7$
- [user2, service2]=11$
- [user2, service3]=3$
- [user2, service1, service3]=10$
- [user2, user3, service1]=13$

How would you write a generic algorithm calculating the total price of all services bought by a given list of users: for instance 36$ for user1 + user2?

Any help will be appreciated! :)

Comment: i think you should elaborate and explain your question more clearly.

Comment: I don't understand, how does all that add up to just $36?

Comment: Because the cost on one row could overlap with another row.

Comment: Yes exactly, sorry if it was not clear :)

Comment: What language is this in, or does it not matter?

Comment: at the end I'll implement it in java, but it does not really matter as I am struggling with the algorithm itself..

Comment: So then I have a question about the bullet points above, what structure is that data stored in or how is that data organized? Because the way that data is set up is very redundant

Comment: each breakdown structure is composed of a list of users ID + a list of services ID